# Comprising the code of jquery validation

Tags: jquery

I want to write common function for text box field. Suppose I have 3 text box. On validation time. I have wrote particular condition for all three text boxes.. like

```
if( conpwd ==='' | conpwd ==='')
    {
        $('#errorconpwd').show('fast');
        $('#conpwd').focus().css({'background-color':'#FFC'});
        return false;
        }   

    if( fname ==='' | fname === null)
    {
        $('#errorfname').show('fast');
        $('#fname').focus().css({'background-color':'#FFC'});
        return false;
        }   

    if( lname ==='' | lname === null)
    {
        $('#errorlname').show('fast');
        $('#lname').focus().css({'background-color':'#FFC'});
        return false;
        }
```

like here if confirmation password field is blank. I have focus it with css property, for fname again i have written n again for last name. now if first name is focused and user enter some text than i want to again make css default. I mean to say instead of writing

```
$('#fname').blur(function(){
   if($('#fname').val()!=''){
     $('#fname').css({'background-color':'#FFF'});
    }
 }
```

Means I want to write combine condition for all. I don't want to write separately for each field. Similary can I comprise above written code for confirmationpassword, fname, lname in one go?

As per my search on google. I want to modify it with $(this) selector..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 for jquery validation plugin, 
here though, you can set a class for everything :

```
<input id=conpwd class=validate>
<input id=fname class=validate>
<input id=lname class=validate>
```

and you can do what you want on the element with that class firing the event using $(this).

```
$('.validate').blur(function(){
  if($(this).val()!=''){
     $(this).css({'background-color':'#FFF'});
    }
 });
```

Comment: Is it possible if we have more than one class. What is limitation for having number of class in one input tag.

Comment: You can have as many as you like given that they are in quotations and they are all one word, like this : `class="validate send_message delete"`

Comment: I have attached class to label to all of these. like...
<input id=conpwd class=validate><label class=error>not correct</label> how can I die this because the way I am doing refreshes the form. I used *if($(this).val()!=''){
     $('.error').hide();
     $(this).css({'background-color':'#FFF'});
    }* though it doesn'y give me error but it refreshes the form..

Comment: To hide your error label when the validation is correct, try `$(this).next('.error').hide();`. else, `.show()`.  `$('.error').hide();` by itself will hide everything that has an error class. Next time you do a form validation however, check out jquery validate, its very quick.

Answer (score 2):

Use [jQuery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation)

Comment: Great...Will surely implement this in some other form.

Answer (score 0):

There is one flexible validation form here: [jQuery Validation](http://www.tectual.com.au/posts/14/jQuery-Validator-Plugin-Validation-Plugin-.html)

Basically it uses a syntax like

```
<input data-validate-presence='true' />
<input data-validate-presence='true' data-validate-email='true' />
```

and automatically apply the rules. in case you need combined checking and complex validations such as serverside uniqueness check you can extend it so easily by extending its **options.validators** and it can takes global effect, so once added you can use this new validator in whole project.

It also flexible enough to give you options to show errors in tooltip, message box or any other format you want. and less than 3 kb.

Some more samples can be found here http://www.tectual.com.au/downloads/jquery/validation/index.html